# Yarn Install fetching from old remote

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and my project is a react project using yarn and git.

In my package.json, my project pulls dependencies from a private github repo using the following format:

```
...

    "dependencies": {
        "dep-name": "git+https://[oauth token]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/[MyOrg]/[dep-name].git#0.1.0",
    }
```

Recently, the oauth token was invalidated and I've had to update it. However, `yarn install` continues to use the old token giving me an authentication error.

So far, I've tried removing the yarn cache (`yarn cache clean`), removing the npm cache (`npm cache clear --force`), removing my nvm cache (`nvm cache clear`) and removing the `yarn.lock` file as well as the `node_modules` folder.

I've also tried removing the global yarn cache, and deleting the `yarn` folder in my `~/var/cache` directory. Still nothing.

Can anyone help?

Edit: I have also run a grep on my project folder for the old token (`grep -R "old-oken"`) and found no results in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - it wasn't using the old token for that dependency, but actually one of the dependencies dependencies was also a private repo and accessed using the old token which was causing the problem